# Overlay transparent activity causing background activity status bar gone

Tags: android, overlay

I'm creating an android project that makes a transparent activity overlays another activity.
Suppose I have two activities A and B. Activity A lead me to transparent activity B which is overlaying the Activity A as a full-screen activity.

I am following the solution from this link
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

but in my case, the transparent activity B causing status bar in Activity A gone, what I'm pursuing is how can I make the transparent activity B overlays the Activity A without affecting it at all.

Thank You

Comment: Post your manifest please.

Comment: Also post an image of current behaviour.